# How to make pdf Non-downloadable on my Ionic3 app?

Tags: php, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, pdf-viewer

I am working on a coaching institute app using Ionic3. they want their pdf not to be downloadable and shareable, only registered students can only view their pdf. All pdf is on their server.
 I am doing this to open pdf but it is using default pdf viewer of the device and so the user is able to download and share the pdf. How to handle this using Php script or Ionic3 end. Thanks in Advance.

```
window.open(pdf_url, '_system', 'location=yes');
```

Comment: maybe try https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/document-viewer/ .. but really all user will have to do is take a screenshot if they want to share your file

Comment: Its ok if they take the screenshot because it will take a lot of time, but if pdf is downloadable they can share it easily. I have tried https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/document-viewer/ .

Comment: PDF will be downloaded anyway to be viewed on the remote device, so if someone really wanted it they can dig into your browsers temp net files folder and copy it.

Comment: Isn't there any way, because i have found international journals pdf non-downloadable.